# ASP.NET - cant GetType() of MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, gettype

I have a MasterPage and get its type as follows:

[alt text http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/masterpage.png](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/masterpage.png)

No problem, this works

Now, when I create an aspx page and try the same thing I get null:

[alt text http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/page.png](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/page.png)

Why?

How can I get this to work?

**NOTE**

The answers below say I need to reference an Assembly.
But how do I do that when I am running this application as an ASP.NET website - there are on compiled DLLs here.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this is occurring is because you are compiling each page individually becuase you are using a website instead of a web project.

So each page is an individual assembly that doesn't know about the other.  If you want to use the GetType I would recommend changing to a web project to make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

In the markup for your aspx page you can specify the master page type you are using like so:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
```

In any case, you can get the type of the current master page back from a call like this in your codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type t;
    t = this.Master.GetType();
}
```

Comment: Above this may work but in my actual problem the MasterPage is not used by the aspx

Comment: Ok, maybe it's best if you explain why you need a reference to the master page then if it's not used by that page? There may be another, easier way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`Type.GetType(string)` requires an assembly-qualified type name.

Comment: I don't have an explicit assembly here, just an ASP.NET website. How should I reference the assembly?

Answer (score 0):

add to what Steve suggested, i use his method all the time, 
also check this MSDN article about MasterType directive.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx